# Image Processing in game engines

Tags: textures, image

I'm going to try and use [GEGL](http://www.gegl.org) to allow real-time texture manipulation on an open-source 3D game engine.

What are the most common and most needed operations used on images, textures in game engines?

Thank you!

Comment: So you're asking what people would want if they were using this engine? Kind of depends on what they wanted to do. And it seems this question is just asking for a list of opinions...

Comment: I'm asking what kind of operations on image manipulation/processing most of the engines out there provide to their users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well generally image manipulation would be kept to a minimum because it's expensive and, if it's done, it's probably done with a shader.

That said, general things might include color replacement and maybe putting two images together.

However, these are generally not done in real time.  Most of the effects are done on what you see and images are already in their ready state.